# How to fix, Htaccess file is not working on server

Tags: .htaccess

Htaccess file is not working on the server and it is working fine at localhost, I am trying to remove the PHP extension and directory from the URL. It is showing the requested URL was not found on this server.

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /views/demo.php to /views/demo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally redirect /views/demo to /views/demo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule (?!^views/)^(.*)$ /views/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Please clarify what is not working?

Comment: Have you enabled the consideration of distributed configuration files on that system? Check the documentation for the `AllowOverride` directive ...

Comment: Also don't forget to monitor your http server's error log file. Maybe the rewriting module is not loaded?

Comment: it is showing the requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: What URL is giving 404 to you?

Comment: yes, Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: The question was, what URL are you requesting, when you get the 404?